# Laravel redirects all resources to the home

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

In a `laravel 5.4` application I have a resource and its controller. When I enter the URL of a resource action (like index) instead of getting the controller function result(JSON), I get redirected to `/home`:
(I already have logged in and I get redirected to my user's `/home`)

my controller:

```
class DreamController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $dreams = $request->user()->dreams()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

  return response()->json(['dreams' => $dreams]);
}
}
```

my route api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::resource('dreams', 'DreamController');
```

my web.php route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('dreams', 'DreamController');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

The application is on my local machine so the url is: 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/dreams` but I get redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`

Comment: Can you show us your URL. It will help to know more.

Comment: Try using the artisan to list your current routes - see if the dream route appears there:  

php artisan route:list

Comment: Yes, the route exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this in web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Auth::routes();
Route::resource('dreams', 'DreamController');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: What is its difference with my current route?

Comment: Have you tried it? Please try it and let me know the result. I have a theory, but not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `api` guard in a web route. The `api` guard check authentication using tokens.

Just replace `api` guard in DreamController `constructor` with `web` guard, which will use session for authentication.

**Use This:-**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:web');
}
```